# Using a string to access a table through DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to pass a string in the LINQ query.

```
string TableName = "db.Countries";

var ActualData = (from n in TableName
                          where n.Record_Instance >= 0
                          select n).OrderBy(primaryColumn);
```

My aim behind this is; I want to put the query in a method and call it whenever I need it. Basically changing the TableName and passing it as a parameter on function call.

Is there a way to do this?

**Update :**
 Workaround :

```
 var TableName = db.Countries;
       GetConditionaldata(TableName,..);

   private object GetConditionaldata( DbSet<Country> TableName, ..)
    {
        var ConditionalData = (from n in TableName
                               where n.Record_Instance >= 0
                               select n).OrderBy(primaryColumn);

        var count = ConditionalData.Count();
        var countries = ConditionalData.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize);
        return countries;
    }
```

But Here, I want have to again specify `DbSet<Country>` as the parameter type. If I can at least find a way to get a Generic Dbset<> Which I can pass on as parameter type for my tableName, then my problem would be solved.

Comment: then you would want Where clause to be dynamic too?

Comment: Please refer the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280422/passing-a-linq-expression-as-a-string

Comment: @sachin I do need that.

Comment: @vishalprajapati  That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @DaljeethSingh this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099435/dynamic-table-name-in-linq

Comment: @Sherlock Thanks for the link, But it didn't satisfy what I actually need. The point being "When you use the non generic DbContext.Set instead of DbContext.Set<T>, you can't use the strongly typed linq queries." Which now gives me two loops to run through,to get my result. Let me update my Question so that I can show the workaround that I have tried.

Comment: You can't have a string-typed object _and_ access it statically-typed. If you want a `DbSet<T>`, you need to provide a `T`. Do you mean you have multiple entities containing a specific property that you want to query on (`Record_Instance`), regardless of the entity type? Then apply an interface to your entities. Perhaps show how you actually use this code and how this is problematic for your scenario.

Comment: Well, you can use *raw* sql query with static part and replace table name dynamically in it. Generics in C# can work only with types known at compile time. We can use reflection to find type dynamically by its string name, but what then ? We still cannot use it as `<T>` parameter.

Comment: **This Solved my Issue :** 
I just created a var with Type Dbset having null value. To Pass a generic Dbset as parameter all you have to do is pass an empty var with Dbset Type.
var TableName = (Dbset)null;
 TableName =db.Countries;
           GetConditionaldata(TableName,..);
       private object GetConditionaldata( DbSet TableName, ..)
        { return countries; }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple entities containing the same property that you want to execute the same query on, then you can introduce an interface:

```
public interface IInstanceRecord
{
    int Record_Instance { get; set; }
}
```

Then apply it to your entities in partial classes (or directly if using Code First):

```
public partial class Country : IInstanceRecord { }
public partial class Foo : IInstanceRecord { }
public partial class Bar : IInstanceRecord { }
```

Now you can make your method generic, and add a constraint that the generic types it operates on must implement `IInstanceRecord`:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetConditionalData<T>(IQueryable<T> dbSet, ...)
    where T : IInstanceRecord
{
    var conditionalData = (from n in dbSet
                           where n.Record_Instance >= 0
                           select n).OrderBy(primaryColumn);

    var count = conditionalData.Count();

    var filteredData = conditionalData.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize);
    return filteredData;
}
```

And call it with whatever `DbSet<T>` (or other `IQueryable<T>`) you want, as long as `T : IInstanceRecord`:

```
var filteredCountries = GetConditionalData(dbContext.Countries);
var filteredFoos = GetConditionalData(dbContext.Foos); 
var filteredBars = GetConditionalData(dbContext.Bars);
```

Comment: Ahh..!! Already did it. I am sorry for not providing detailed info before. I already have all the entity classes implementing an interface for the record instance{ISyncInstance}. What I want is I have different entity classes with different properties each. Now I am performing queries for all these entities. I wanted to create methods for 3 different types of queries that I am performing and just call the method when i need it.
- My existing Code design is very lengthy and messy but works fine, Just wanted to modify it.

Comment: You can apply the same pattern there. Again, if you want statically-typed queries, you need to provide type information at compile-time. There's no way around it.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. Thanks :)

Comment: This Solved my Issue : I just created a var with Type Dbset having null value. To Pass a generic Dbset as parameter all you have to do is pass an empty var with Dbset Type. var TableName = (Dbset)null; TableName =db.Countries; GetConditionaldata(TableName,..); private object GetConditionaldata( DbSet TableName, ..) { return countries; }